# When a catapult is cocked back, is the energy stored primarily in stretching of the rope, or bending of the wooden frame?

Tags: forces

Referring to an onager or catapult like this:

[image: Catapult]

I searched it but couldnt find a good answer. I believe that theoretically it could work either way. Likely its at least a little bit of both, but where is the energy stored predominantly?

Answer (score 0):

For a spring obeying hookes law (which a rope is at least approximately), the energy stored is $E=\frac{1}{2}kx^2$ with $x$ the path the spring is deflected, and $k$ the stiffness. To look where most of the energy is stored, look for the part that is deformed the most - the rope.

As for the bending of the wooden frame, it's hard to see how that actually contributes to the energy of the projectile with an onager as pictured. The moment the projectile is released, does the force resulting from the bending of the frame actually act on the projectile? Likely not.

Comment: Well, if you think about it, a catapult could work even with a totally inelastic rope. The twisting action shortens the rope bundle, thus bending the frame. When the arm is released, the frame pulls the rope bundle and lengthens it by untwisting it. The untwisting action moves the arm. I'm not saying that's what happens predominantly, but it's certainly possible.

Answer (score 0):

An "onager or catapult like this" with rope like that wouldn't work at all, so it's a bad picture.

You need to use a sinew composite material (probably with horse hair), as was used in Roman and Greek torsion-spring catapults.

The composite-material torsion-spring was a technically difficult product requiring specialized knowledge, and torsion-spring catapults were replaced with the much simpler rope-pull mangoner and then the counter-weight catapult.

When your energy comes from a torsion spring, rather than a counterweight or men on ropes, their isn't any particular advantage to having a long firing arm. And since the energy is limited to the torsion spring, you probably won't have a load that big or an arm that heavy. So actual torsion-spring ballista don't look like that picture at all.

Comment: That's an interesting observation but it doesn't really answer my question. I don't doubt that the arm length or rope type is not depicted accurately since this does appear to be a video game asset. But that being said, I think if you built this exact design it would function. Perhaps very weakly for the reasons you stated.

Comment: You can build a model something like that using a rubber band instead of a rope. Using a string, it won't actually function -- it won't be able to throw the rock out of the sling.

Comment: If I have time I may rig up a sling like that to one of my catapults and see what happens, just to see if it works at all. But it's not pertinent to my question either way. I'm interested in the main torsion spring and how it works.

Answer (score -1):

it looks like the image you have is a Trebuchet, a kind of catapult that uses the counterweight's stored energy. A cranking mechanism lifts a heavy counterweight attached to the catapult boom via a pulley. Upon releasing the counterweight it falls and releases its energy to pull the boom.

Another type of catapult, mangonel, uses the energy of a long rope stretched or wound around a shaft as a source of energy.

In that version, the energy stored in the rope is released by releasing the restraining rope.
In either case, the contribution of the wood frame is insignificant.

Comment: I think you have these the wrong way around, the image shows a mangonel with the energy stored in the rope.

Comment: Take a second look. It definitely uses twisted rope.

Comment: @Drew, my apologies, the heavy-looking white suspended rocks confused me. however, the answer is still valid. the deflection of the boom under tension is minimal and doesn't contribute much energy when released.

Comment: The heavy block (it is intentionally heavy) is a shock absorber to stop the throwing arm from smashing through the cross member.